# Parsing with Python Help me

Tags: python

How can I pull all coordinates value (56.10457, 47.211815,36.130162, 67.135758) from the entire text?

```
   <script>
         data = milestonesMap.getEmptyData();

                                    data.points.push({
                    properties: {
                        
                        balloonContentHeader: "CORDON",
                    },
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [46.10457, 67.211815]
                    }
                });
                                                data.points.push({
                    properties: {
                        
                        balloonContentHeader: "CORDON",
                    },
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [36.130162, 67.135758]
                    }
                });
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/r/21/milestones'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)
filteredNews = []
allNews = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: You are looking for a JavaScript parser. Such requests are off-topic here, but try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please see this Q and A on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418442/20384561. Also, please note that you must have a Minimum Reproducable Example and show what you have tried. Stack Overflow is not for people to just write code for you - if you show what you have tried to do, we will be able to help you much more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

user regex:

```
coord = re.findall("coordinates: \[([0-9., ]*),([0-9., ]*)\]", soup)
```

output

```
[('46.10457', ' 67.211815'), ('36.130162', ' 67.135758')]
```

or just `re.findall("coordinates: \[([0-9., ]*)\]", soup)` to have both long, lat as one tuple